# populate a select in ASP.net MVC3 with Data in the database using nHibernate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, select

I need to populate the data which is in the database fields using nHibernate mapping for a select in ASP.net MVC3... Please send me a sample code of how to do it..

Regards
Srividhya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller which will populate this view model (hardcode some values at the beginning just to make sure that it works and you have a mockup screens to show to your users):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Items = new[] 
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and finally a view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedItemId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text")
)
```

The next step could consist into defining a model, setting the mapping for this model, a repository allowing you to fetch the model with NHibernate and finally call this repository in the controller action and map the returned model to the view model I used in the example:

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface IItemsRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Item> GetItems();
}
```

and now the controller becomes:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IItemsRepository _repository;
    public HomeController(IItemsRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = _repository.GetItems();
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Items = items.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = item.Id.ToString(),
                Text = item.Name
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

OK, we are making progress little by little. Now you can write unit tests for this controller action.

The next step would be to implement this repository:

```
public class ItemsRepositoryNHibernate : IItemsRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(
            "Out of the scope for this question. Checkout the NHibernate manual"
        );
    }
}
```

and the last step is to instruct your dependency injection framework to pass the correct implementation of the repository to the `HomeController`. For example if you use [Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160946/ninject-mvc3-invalidoperationexception-sequence-contains-no-elements/5161094#5161094) all you need to do is to write a module that will configure the kernel:

```
public class RepositoriesModule : StandardModule 
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Bind<IItemsRepository>().To<ItemsRepositoryNHibernate>();
    }
}
```